# peclでインストールしたモジュールが反映されない

Tags: php

peclでfannというモジュールをインストールしたのですがphpinfoにも表示されず使えません
pecl list でインストールされているのは確認できます
apacheの再起動もしてみましたがダメでした
何か反映する方法があるのでしょうか？

こちらを参考にしてインストールは行いました
http://qiita.com/ukk0/items/6ae19800fee96291de2b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

インストールされた環境がわからないので詳細は省略しますが、peclでextensionをインストールした場合、設定ファイルの追記が必要になります。

例えばRedHat系のLinux等なら`/etc/php.d`以下のファイルが参考になると思うので、同様に作成すれば読み込めるはずです。

また、Apache HTTPDやphp-fpm等サーバーを経由している場合、この変更後にそれらのリロードも必要です。